# Get parent of register in llvm

Tags: llvm

In llvm used to be this great function (I don't know which version they are using here):

```
const unsigned* llvm::TargetRegisterInfo::getSuperRegisters(unsigned RegNo)
```

http://legup.eecg.utoronto.ca/doxygen/classllvm_1_1TargetRegisterInfo.html#90b85b889ff636c6bdd40b7543343473

Unfortunately I am using llvm 3.4, where this function does not exist. Is there something with similar functionality? Or is there an easy workaround to get all the parent registers of a given register?

Answer (score 0):

Should have read the docu more carefully. Here is the answer:

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1MCSuperRegIterator.html

llvm::MCSuperRegIterator expects a physical register in its constructor and then iterates over all its parents.